# How can I get Google Chrome Application Mode to preseve the theme?

Tags: google-chrome

In Windows, using Version 51.0.2704.106 m, normal mode:

```
"GoogleChromePortable\GoogleChromePortable.exe" C:\temp\temp.html
```

shows the theme:

[image]

but Application Mode:

```
"GoogleChromePortable\GoogleChromePortable.exe" --app=file
://C:/temp/temp.html
```

does not:

[image]

Comment: Why was this taken out of webapps?? It is about a web app.

Comment: A web browser is not a web application.